# python opencv imwrite ... can't find params

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv with python. I wanted to do an cv2.imwrte:

```
cv2.imwrite('myimage.png', my_im)
```

The only problem is that opencv does not recognize the params constants:

```
cv2.imwrite('myimage.png', my_im, cv2.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0)
```

It cannot find CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I can't find key `CV_XXXXX` in the `cv2` module:

1. Try `cv2.XXXXX`
2. Failing that, use `cv2.cv.CV_XXXXX`

In your case, `cv2.cv.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION`.

---

#### More info.

The docs for OpenCV (cv2 interface) are a bit confusing.

Usually parameters that look like `CV_XXXX` are actually `cv2.XXXX`.

I use the following to search for the relevant `cv2` constant name. Say I was looking for `CV_MORPH_DILATE`. I'll search for any constant with `MORPH` in it:

```
import cv2
nms = dir(cv2) # list of everything in the cv2 module
[m for m in nms if 'MORPH' in m]
# ['MORPH_BLACKHAT', 'MORPH_CLOSE', 'MORPH_CROSS', 'MORPH_DILATE',
#  'MORPH_ELLIPSE', 'MORPH_ERODE', 'MORPH_GRADIENT', 'MORPH_OPEN',
#  'MORPH_RECT', 'MORPH_TOPHAT']
```

From this I see that `MORPH_DILATE` is what I'm looking for.

**However**, sometimes the constants have not been moved from the `cv` interface to the `cv2` interface yet.

In that case, you can find them under `cv2.cv.CV_XXXX`.

So, I looked for `IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION` for you and couldn't find it (under `cv2....`), and so I looked under `cv2.cv.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION`, and hey presto! It's there:

```
>>> cv2.cv.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION
16
```

Comment: This is such a freaking handy snippet for this and so many other instances!

Comment: indeed, very useful approach to find stuff when it's not where you think it is.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#gga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42acad2548321c69ab9c0582fd51e75ace1d0 `[cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, [0-9]]`

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on mathematical.coffee to ignore case and look in both namespaces:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
nms  = [(n.lower(), n) for n in dir(cv)] # list of everything in the cv module
nms2 = [(n.lower(), n) for n in dir(cv2)] # list of everything in the cv2 module

search = 'imwrite'

print "in cv2\n ",[m[1] for m in nms2 if m[0].find(search.lower())>-1]
print "in cv\n ",[m[1] for m in nms if m[0].find(search.lower())>-1]

>>> 
in cv2
  ['imwrite']
in cv
  ['CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY', 'CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION', 'CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY']
>>>
```

Hopefully this problem will go away in some later release of cv2...

Answer (score 1):

the compression style is automatically chosen from the file extension. see the cv2.imwrite help [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite).

however you might still be interested to know all the possible flags used by all the possible functions in cv2 and cv modules.

look for cv2.txt and cv.txt on your computer. they will be where the opencv modules are installed. at the bottom of those text files are a list of the flags used by the respective modules.

just in case you don't find them, you can download the ones i have from here, though they are from august 2011:

- [cv2.txt](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2AJ7rliSQubYks1c1Vrc0VObjQ/edit?usp=sharing)
- [cv.txt](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2AJ7rliSQubNm4xNUJNYlhIdzg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

in fact, with cv2 style API, this constant is replaced with `cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION`.